# Abrir documento do mesmo diretório em nova janela após submit

Tags: javascript, jquery

No meu diretório tenho as seguintes paginas em HTML:
public_html
// Index.html
// comprovante_protocolo.html
// protocolo_menu.html

Na pagina "protocolo_menu" montamos um formulario. O objetivo é que depois de dar o submit no formulario abra a pagina "comprovante_protocolo" em uma nova aba. O código para que os dados do protocolo sejam cadastrados é:

```js
function EditarCadastrarProtocolo() {
    if (document.getElementById("idProtocolo").value == "") {
        AdicionarProtocolo();
    } else {
        EditarProtocolo(document.getElementById("idProtocolo").value);
    }
}

function AdicionarProtocolo() {

    var cod = GerarIdProtocolo();
    $("#idProtocolo").val(cod);
    var select = document.getElementById("clienteProtocolo");
    var clienteSelecionado = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
    var protocolo = JSON.stringify({
        codigo: cod,
        data: $("#dataProtocolo").val(),
        codCliente: clienteSelecionado,
        observacoes: $("#observacoes").val()
    });
    tbProtocolos.push(protocolo);
    localStorage.setItem("tbProtocolos", JSON.stringify(tbProtocolos));
    alert("Protocolo " + cod + " Cadastrado com Sucesso!");
    ListarProtocolos();
}
```

Estou tentando fazercom que depois do submit a pagina "comprovante_protocolo.html" abra em uma nova aba, onde será apresentado um formulario com os dados cadastrados e demais informações para serem entregues ao cliente e assinadas. Pensei em colocar o código assim:

' if (document.getElementById("idProtocolo").value == "") {
            AdicionarProtocolo();
            window.open......;'

Não deu certo e não achei nada parecido na internet, alguém tem alguma ideia de como fazer isso?

Comment: A maioria dos usuários da web não visualizam pop-us já que a maioria dos navegadores tem um modo embutido para bloqueio. Será que seu popup não vai cair nesse cenário?

Answer (score 1):

Basta colocar target="_blank" no formulário

```
<form target="_blank" ............
```

Comment: consegui fazer colocando um código pra abrir o documento em um popup

Comment: Pois então, aqui não vai abrir sua popup e acredito que em muitos usuários também não.

Answer (score 0):

Vejo duas formas:

1- postar o conteúdo diretamente na URL do comprovante, que nesse caso será responsável por fazer o insert e depois exibir o resultado, usando o target _blank no fomulário, como disse o colega Leo Caracciolo;

2- postar o conteúdo no script que fará o insert e depois redirecionar para o comprovante, enviando novamente as informações para preenchimento do comprovante (desavantagem: as informações serão processadas duas vezes)